# Does audio OP-AMP circuit needs output capacitors?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, sound, preamp, headphones

I saw schematics with and without output capacitors. So in the end - do you really need capacitors in the output?

- I am using OPA2134 operational amplifier.  I plan to use it both as headphone and line amplifier.

Schematics without output capacitors:

*
[image]
*
[image]

Comment: Do you mean DC-blocking capacitors in series with the output?

Comment: Yes, probably. In the second schematic from top it would probably be after R5 resistor.   Is it really necessary to have as lots of schematics don't include it?

Comment: You should generally avoid buildings things which you do not understand. In this case, there is no danger to you but if you carry this mentality of picking random things off the internet and just building them because someone said its ok - it may hurt you or cause damage to you or your environment. A question you should be asking instead of do I need an output cap, is to ask instead *"What is the purpose of an output cap ?" *You will then understand why you do, or do not need one for nearly all other applications rather than this one specific one.

Comment: Look, I built a tube amplifier myself. I DO understand what I am doing and I DO understand that capacitors only pass AC voltage through them. Don't hurry and say that I don't understand what I am doing. I'm just lost in this case - is the capacitor necessary or not - that's all I am asking. In other words will DC get to the output or not? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for being harsh though

Comment: But that's sort of the point. If you can't analyze the circuit to determine whether there's DC on the output, then by definition, you don't know what you're doing. After all, that's what you're asking us to do!

Comment: Perhaps you are right. That's why I am asking I quess.. Alright, back to the topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of the circuits you show, the input is AC-coupled, with a DC return to ground, and the feedback path is also referenced to ground. Therefore, the only DC on the output will be due to the internal offset of the opamp itself, plus the input bias offset, multiplied by the closed-loop gain of the circuit (which is 10 in both cases).

Since this should be an insignificant value, DC blocking capacitors on the output are not required.

Answer (score 1):

With the +/- supplies there will only be a small amount of voltage on the output (from the amplifier input offset voltage x10 and bias current x 101K x 10).

Probably not a problem if it's less than 50mV. Try to calculate the maximum output offset voltage, it should be pretty straightfoward from the datasheet specs.